# Does any particular digital sensor size have an advantage for projection?

Tags: sensor-size

I presently shoot with slide film and project the images.  I am considering digital.  I would like to continue projecting the images via TV or digital projector.  Which sensor would perform better for my projection needs?  APSC or
full frame?

Comment: Your subject matter and shooting conditions will determine the answer to your question. As asked, the correct answer is "Either, depending on what you're shooting and under what conditions." The question is currently way too broad.

Comment: @MichaelClark - I'd disagree it is too broad.  Sure it is too broad to go in to what other factors would determine what they should use, but that isn't what the question is asking.  It's asking which sensor would be better for this particular criteria.  The answer is simply that neither one has a particular advantage for the given context.

Comment: Oh, one sensor certainly has an advantage over the other for the OP's shooting context. It's just that the question, as asked, does not allow that context to be known.

Comment: The full shooting context, sure, but the OP wasn't asking about other factors.  They were asking about one specific factor and the answer for that factor is that it doesn't matter.  You are redefining what the OP is asking to make it too broad be cause you want to be able to answer one or the other and then branding the question as too broad.  Instead, why not just answer the question they asked, unless you are arguing that projection will somehow alter how the other aspects play in to it.

Comment: The key phrase to my eyes is, "Which sensor would perform better for **my** projection needs?" Unless we know what his needs are we can't properly answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Either should be fine - typical DSLR resolution is still a lot higher than typical digital projectors.

There's always the option of having slides made from your digital files and using your existing projector. That might give you higher resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Typical consumer TV and projector is around 1080P i.e. 1920 x 1080 ~ 2 MegaPixel(MP). A 4K TV is ~ 8.3 MP.  And 4K projector will be pretty expensive currently.

So current consumer range 8 megapixel digital camera is sufficient.

Full frame DSLR will make no different in your 4K TV/projector, after all , it is all about shooting skill.

OTH, if you are talking about converting film to digital, then 20MP film to digital converter will persevered more details. HOWEVER, it make no different on the digital projector/TV due to current projection pixel limit.

Comment: Does the question specify that *resolution* is the *only* consideration? If the images are taken in very low light the sensor size could have a very significant impact on the result. Ditto for very high dynamic range scenes where the typically larger pixels of larger sensors perform better..

Comment: @MichaelClark Well, it will be too broad, from past to future, from old digital sensor vs new, old software vs new light handling software,  lens etc  ;-)